# Is there a word for "the length of time from birth to the age of majority"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word should be usable in place of any word that indicates a span of time, such as "week", "decade", or "saeculum"; specifically in the phrase "...once per [time-period]...".

Comment: If you stick to legal definition, minority is appropriate. Otherwise, you may refer to "youth".

Comment: Could you give more context?  It's not clear why you want to say "once per minority" instead of "once per child."

Comment: @Nathaniel It's in reference to societal events, not from the viewpoint of a parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technical term (in legal use) is

> **minority** n.
>   3. Law The state or period of being younger than the age for legal adulthood ....

[minority. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved November 18 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/minority.]

In non-technical uses,

> **child·hood** n.
>   1. The time or state of being a child.

[childhood. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved November 18 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/childhood.]

serves the same function.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this usage of "minority". It is precise, but it sounds awkward in the intended phrase. "Childhood" may suffice. I'll update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

**Minority**.  It applies to both the state and the time period:

> the period during which a person is below legal age. ([Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/minority))
>
> the state or period of being under full legal age. ([Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/minority))

Answer (score 2):

Be ***[underage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/underage):***

> - (Law) below the required or standard age, esp below the legal age for voting or drinking

The Free Dictionary

***[Nonage](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nonage)***:

> - (law) the state of being under any of various ages at which a person may legally enter into certain transactions, such as the making of binding contracts, marrying, etc

Collins Dictionary

Comment: +1 for nonage, though the word seems to be [in a sad state of decline](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nonage&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "coming-of-age"? Not precise perhaps, and more of a phrase, but I think it at least indicates the period that lasts until one reaches adulthood...

Comment: "coming-of-age" describes the transition between childhood and adulthood, not the period of time between birth and "coming-of-age"

Comment: Yeah, true, I realized that after I wrote it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider,

***spring of life***.

> : the first stage and freshest period [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spring)

***seedtime of life***

> seedtime: the season for sowing seed
>
> *The seedtime of life is too short, and its hours are too few, to spend in baffling detraction* [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/seedtime)