# Antonym of underage or minority

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am looking for one word (formal preferably) that defines the state or period of not being under full legal age, i.e. the opposite of what is asked in this question:

[Is there a word for "the length of time from birth to the age of majority"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288092/is-there-a-word-for-the-length-of-time-from-birth-to-the-age-of-majority)

Is there such a word?

Comment: Legal adult, age of majority

Comment: Adulthood, maturity, majority

Comment: "Of age" is sometimes used.

Comment: You mention this being for an online contest; is the restriction is for legal purposes? Is there s specific age you need entrants to be over, if so who not state that age?

Comment: The answers given so far correctly answer your question as it’s posed, but for a contest, be VERY careful using a general term whose meaning varies with jurisdictions AND circumstances. There are some 20 million [emancipated minors](https://books.google.com/books?id=mIwqCHqocOoC&pg=PA111&dq=%22emancipated+minors%22+%22legally+adults%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9wKjDpPrMAhWIaz4KHabtApAQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22emancipated%20minors%22%20%22legally%20adults%22&f=false) in the US who are adults & of age in the eyes of the law. Resolve the space issues elsewhere & use a specific age (& above) instead.

Comment: @Spagirl the contest will be advertised online but it is not an online contest. It will take place in a country where the age of legal majority is 18 years. The restriction is one of the rules for participating, I just need it to be as formal as possible. I already chose the single word suggested by NVZ, _adult_, since I believe people will understand it quickly without raising further questions. Josh's suggestion is also very acceptable: "He's not underage, he's an _adult_." VS "(...), he's _of age_", but someone could always ask, which age?

Comment: @PapaPoule You make a good point and it's likely that some people will think like that as well. We probably need to reference the 18 somewhere...

Comment: @CPHPython I think you should consider it safer to be explicit, and if you *know* what the legal requirement it it seems safest to state it with minimum scope for misunderstanding. You could always use 'adult' but clearly footnote the definition if you don't want to put it in the main text for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adult** (or "legal adult" to be specific)  — [TFD](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/adult)

> *(legal definition)* **a person who has attained the age of legal majority.**
>
> A person who by virtue of attaining a certain age, generally eighteen, is regarded in the eyes of the law as being able to manage his or her own affairs.
>
> The age specified by law, called the legal age of majority, indicates that a person acquires full legal capacity to be bound by various documents, such as contracts and deeds, that he or she makes with others and to commit other legal acts such as voting in elections and entering marriage.
>
> The age at which a person becomes an adult varies from state to state and often varies within a state, depending upon the nature of the action taken by the person. Thus, a person wishing to obtain a license to operate a motor vehicle may be considered an adult at age sixteen, but may not reach adulthood until age eighteen for purposes of marriage, or age twenty-one for purposes of purchasing intoxicating liquors.
>
> Anyone who has not reached the age of adulthood is legally considered an infant.

Age of majority — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_majority)

> Age of majority should not be confused with the age of sexual consent, marriageable age, school leaving age, drinking age, driving age, voting age, smoking age, etc., which each may be independent of, and sometimes set at a different age from, the age of majority

Comment: Thanks NVZ, so in this phrase "The contestant is an **adult**." is it clear that the person is not underage? Or is it required to place the word legal before it?

Comment: @CPHPython "Adult" should be fine. Tell me, what kind of contest is it?

Comment: The person has to complete a specific action in order to be able to participate and win the prize, this will be advertised online.

Comment: @CPHPython "Adult" is fine. But depends on your regional laws. At what age is a person defined as an adult there? OR you could be specific by saying persons 18 years old and above.

Comment: I understand, one word is ideal though (due to space restrictions). By logic there is no "under full legal aged" adult in any English speaking country that I know of, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Due to potential conflicts between the laws of nature and man, the term might be better expressed as "legal adult" to be clear which standard is being employed.

Answer (score 3):

You can  use the expression,

***be/come of age***:

> - to reach the age when you are legally recognized as an adult.

[(Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-of-age)

Comment: Thanks Josh (I will upvote when I am able to do so), I am particularly looking for a word that can replace the words in angle quotes in this sentence: "The contestant must be a «full legal aged» person in order to participate".

Comment: @CPHPython "..must be an adult" or "..legal adult" works fine.

Comment: @COHPyton / it depends on context. Adult does not necessarily refer to legal adult. The antonym of *underage*  is *of age*.

Comment: "The contestant must be a *person of age* in order to participate", looks fine. :)